# fix Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 without xcode

Tags: xcode, cordova, parse-platform

I'm using cordova and Parse phonegap push notifdication plugin (https://github.com/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin).
When I try to build my app using intel XDK, it gives the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"OBJC_CLASS$FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
_OBJC_CLASS$PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
"_FBTokenInformationTokenKey", referenced from:
-[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy accessToken] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
-[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setAccessToken:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
"_OBJC_METACLASS$FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
_OBJC_METACLASS$PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
"_FBTokenInformationExpirationDateKey", referenced from:
-[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy cacheTokenInformation:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
-[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy expirationDate] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
-[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setExpirationDate:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS$FBAppCall", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
"_FBTokenInformationUserFBIDKey", referenced from:
-[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy facebookId] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
-[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setFacebookId:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS$FBRequest", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS$_FBSession", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I fix this without xcode since I'm building it on intel xdk?
Can I manually change any config file?